# How do I select the group with the least number of null values in a groupby?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, database, ansi-sql

Example:

```
row_number |id |firstname | middlename | lastname |
0          | 1 | John     | NULL       | Doe      |
1          | 1 | John     | Jacob      | Doe      |
2          | 2 | Alison   | Marie      | Smith    |
3          | 2 | NULL     | Marie      | Smith    |
4          | 2 | Alison   | Marie      | Smith    |
```

I'm trying to figure out how to groupby id, and then grab the row with the least number of NULL values for each groupby, dropping any extra rows that contain the least number of NULLs is fine (for example, dropping row_number 4 since it ties row_number 2 for the least number of NULLS where id=2)

The answer for this example would be the row_numbers 1 and 2

Preferably would be ANSI SQL, but I can translate other languages (like python with pandas) if you can think of a way to do it

Edit:
Added a row for the case of tie-breaking.

Comment: Why would it be "1 and 2"?  Why not the other rows?  And shouldn't the results summarize "1 and 2" into a single row?

Comment: rows 1 and 2 have the least number of NULL values for their group (id)

Comment: So if we groupby id, then we have the groups that contain id=1 and id=2. I need to count the number of NULLs in these groups, and select the row with the least number of NULLs

Comment: I think he means the value in `row_number` column is 1 or 2, which would be actual row 2 and 3...

Comment: why you tag pandas ....

Comment: If you want to use pandas, df.groupby('id').first() will do the trick for you

Comment: Because I would be just as happy with an answer that uses pandas as one that uses sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this pandas, you can do it this way:

```
df[df.assign(NC = df.isnull().sum(1)).groupby('id')['NC'].transform(lambda x: x == x.min())]
```

Output:

```
   row_number  id firstname middlename lastname
1           1   1      John      Jacob      Doe
2           2   2    Alison      Marie    Smith
```

For tiebreaker:

Add a row:

```
df.loc[4,['row_number','id','firstname','middlename','lastname']] = ['4',2,'Mary','Maxine','Maxwell']
```

Then use `groupby`, `transform`, and `idxmin`:

```
df[df.index == df.assign(NC = df.isnull().sum(1)).groupby('id')['NC'].transform('idxmin')]
```

Output:

```
  row_number id firstname middlename lastname
1          1  1      John      Jacob      Doe
2          2  2    Alison      Marie    Smith
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Something I failed to mention was tie breakers when two rows contain the same number of NULLs. How would you drop one of them?

Comment: @MylesHollowed see update, you can use idxmin which find the index of the first occurance of a minimum value.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you want the rows with the fewest `null` values.  I would suggest:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by (case when firstname is null then 1 else 0 end) + 
                                         (case when middlename is null then 1 else 0 end) + 
                                         (case when lastname is null then 1 else 0 end)
                               ) as seqnum

      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This is ANSI-standard SQL.

Comment: the ranking has to be *per id*

Comment: This works great, but as Vamsi mentioned, I need to be able to use it in a groupby