# Combine duplicates in Pandas to obtain the maximum amount of data possible

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, python-3.8

I have a large data table with several duplicates. The goal is to complement these duplicates to obtain a row with the maximum amount of information.
Imagine a pandas data frame with the following structure:

```html
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d = {'id': [1,1,1,2,2,3], 'col1': [25,np.NaN,25,3,np.NaN,1], 'col2':[np.NaN,'rrt',np.NaN,np.NaN,'sdf',np.NaN], 'col3':[300,300,np.NaN,500,500,600]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df
   id  col1 col2   col3
0   1  25.0  NaN  300.0
1   1   NaN  rrt  300.0
2   1  25.0  NaN    NaN
3   2   3.0  NaN  500.0
4   2   NaN  sdf  500.0
5   3   1.0  NaN  600.0
```

The result I wish to obtain is the following:

```html
   id  col1 col2   col3
0   1  25.0  rrt  300.0
1   1  25.0  NaN  300.0
2   1   NaN  rrt  300.0
3   1  25.0  NaN    NaN
4   2   3.0  sdf  500.0
5   2   3.0  NaN  500.0
6   2   NaN  sdf  500.0
7   3   1.0  NaN  600.0
```

(Afterward, I could use the solution of the" [How do I select the group with the least number of null values in a groupby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391838/how-do-i-select-the-group-with-the-least-number-of-null-values-in-a-groupby) " thread to obtain.

```html
   id  col1 col2   col3
0   1  25.0  rrt  300.0
1   2   3.0  sdf  500.0
3   3   1.0  NaN  600.0
```

)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. I hope this will help you,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'id': [1,1,1,2,2,3], 'col1': [25,np.NaN,25,3,np.NaN,1], 'col2':[np.NaN,'rrt',np.NaN,np.NaN,'sdf',np.NaN], 'col3':[300,300,np.NaN,500,500,600]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df2 = df1.groupby('id').agg({'col1': max, 'col3':max}).reset_index()
col = []
for index in range(len(df2)):
    group_list = df1.groupby('id')['col2'].get_group(index + 1).tolist()
    new_list = [item for item in group_list if not(pd.isnull(item)) == True]
    if len(new_list)<1:
        new_list.append(np.nan)
    col.append(new_list[0])
df2['col2'] = col
final_df = pd.concat([df1, df2.dropna()], axis=0).sort_values(by=['id', 'col3']).reset_index().drop(columns='index')
```

The final dataframe is,

```
   id  col1 col2   col3
0   1  25.0  NaN  300.0
1   1   NaN  rrt  300.0
2   1  25.0  rrt  300.0
3   1  25.0  NaN    NaN
4   2   3.0  NaN  500.0
5   2   NaN  sdf  500.0
6   2   3.0  sdf  500.0
7   3   1.0  NaN  600.0
```

the df2 output is,

```
   id  col1   col3 col2
0   1  25.0  300.0  rrt
1   2   3.0  500.0  sdf
2   3   1.0  600.0  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @Berlin Benilo, I think you got the right path. Nevertheless, I would use merge instead of the iteration you proposed.

Comment: @Andres Perez Yeah right. It is not a much optimised code. Thanks for your feedback:).